# Nonrepresentative sample for causal analysis

Tags: regression, sampling, causality, representative

Suppose I observe an outcome $Y_i$ for a binary policy $Z_i$ with random assignment and no spillovers such that $Y_i(1),Y_i(0) \perp Z_i$. I run the regression

$$
y_i = \alpha + \beta z_i + \varepsilon_i
$$

to get the average treatment effect of the policy $E[Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)]$. However, the dataset I have at hand was collected as a non-random sample which is not representative of the population. There exist no weights to compensate that.

Will $\hat{\beta}$ give an unbiased estimate of $E[Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)]$?

Answer (score 3):

Random assignment of treatment will give you an unbiased estimate of the target quantity on the sample, however this may not transfer to the population if your sample does not represent the population.

Illustrative non-formal example:

Q: Does regular exercise at a heart rate of 170 beats per minute improve health?

1. Sample of healthy 25 year olds: *yes*
2. Sample of 90 year olds with a pacemaker: *probably no*

If your population is mainly 90 year olds with pacemakes but your sample is mainly healthy 25 year olds, you would clearly get a biased estimate for the population effect of the intervention (doing the exercise).

Comment: I thought so too. Essentially, we have to assume either (i) treatment effect homogeneity or that (ii) sampling probability does not correlate with treatment effect (as it does in your example). In practice, assumption (ii) may not be too strong for nonprobability samples? That's the example I am thinking about. We are not restricting the sample, but participants have to self-enrol to the sampling frame.

Comment: I think that really depends on the application. If you take my exercise example, I can well imagine that mostly healthy young people would self-enroll. I could imagine it might work in your application but it's probably best to spend some time on crafting the argument and checking if it is convincing.